# Dead code при проверке массива на одинаковые пары чисел с двух концов к центру

Tags: java, массивы, for

```
public class Test {
    public static boolean allPairsEqual(int[] a) {
        for (int i = 0, j = a.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
            if (a[i] != a[j])
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("For call allPairsEqual({7,-2,3,9,3,-2,7}), result is " +
                allPairsEqual(new int[]{7, -2, 3, 9, 3, -2, 7}));
        System.out.println("For call allPairsEqual({7,-2,3,9,3,2,7}), result is " +
                allPairsEqual(new int[]{7, -2, 3, 9, 3, 2, 7}));
    }
}
```

Когда запускаю код, он пропускает цикл. Среда пишет `Dead Code`. Если писать через `while()`, то работает нормально. Не могу понять, почему цикл `for` он просто пропускает. По моей версии - это из-за значения, которое я вношу. Метод заранее не знает какой будет массив и просто скипает цикл. Буду благодарен за объяснение.

Comment: Код приведённый выше отрабатывает без ошибок. У вас сообщение при выполнении или компиляции?

Comment: Он компилируется, но при этом цикл for пропускает и просто возвращает true во всех случаях  хотя по логике не должен. Этот же стейтмент  через цикл while выполняет задачу. Среда разработки подчеркивает i++ с подписью Dead code. В дебагере видно как он на цикл даже не смотрит а сразу пропускает

Comment: Это какой то глюк. Обновите проект, и внимательно проверьте условие. Пропуск цикла выполняется только если условие ложно. В режиме отладки убедитесь что у вас правильное присваивание i и j. Я ради интереса проверил ваш код в Eclipse, отработал без ошибки.

Comment: Код должен выдать правду в первом случае и ложь во втором случае. У вас так получилось?Да действительно в другой среде он работает нормально...

Comment: Да, выводит две строки. Поэтому либо опечатки в условии, либо глючит проект.

Comment: `return false; else return true;`  В общем это была моя ошибка, я не заметил лишнюю строчку, забыл ее удалить.... Спасибо за помощь)@kio